# Is there a solution for 22.04 and kernel 6.5.0-14 - 21 (22.04) for users of NVidia cards using the Nouveau driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 22.04, graphics

I'm running 22.04 LTS with an Asus NVidia GeForce GT 730.
I'm using the Ubuntu provided video driver (Nouveau).

Since upgrading my kernel to 6.5, I notice that my monitor goes to sleep (power save) mode as soon as the system attempts to display the graphical login screen.  Attempting to switch to a character console wakes the monitor but I still have a blank screen.  Switching back to the graphical login screen puts the monitor back to sleep. Shutting down the system wakes the monitor and splash screen displays during shutdown.

My current solution is to use my previous 6.2 kernel.

I've been reading in the forums about users having problems with recompiling their driver source, gcc version mismatches v11 (6.2 kernel) vs v12 (6.5 kernel) and some driver source incompatibilities with the new compiler.

I'm wondering how soon users might expect a fix for the stock driver or if we should expect a fix?
I've got a 2nd Linux systems also 22.04 with a GT 610 that has no issues with the latest 6.5 kernel.

The command

```
dkms status
```

returns nothing. And

```
apt-cache policy gcc-12
```

returns

> gcc-12:
> Installed: (none)
> Candidate: 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04

Bug Reported
[link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/+bug/2051875)

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1500676/edit) your question and add the output of `dkms status`?  Also, you might already have `gcc-12` installed.  `apt-cache policy gcc-12`

Comment: You might have an bug with the nouveau driver then.  I would recommend trying to reinstall the `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` driver or file a bug against it for the 6.5.0-14-generic kernel issue:  `ubuntu-bug xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`.  As far as `gcc-12` goes, you can install it and update the link.  `sudo apt install gcc-12`  and then `sudo ln -s -f /usr/bin/gcc-12 /usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: I changed the term "Ubuntu driver" to "Nouveau". If this does not match your requirements, please revert the edit. TIA.

Comment: I've attempted to run ubuntu-bug xserver-xorg-video-nouveau multiple times over the last week and I get 505 bad gateway errors.  I'll attempt manually.

Comment: See bug 2051457.  I'm finding that with the gcc-12 installed, no link changes to change the default gcc-11, and a 6.5 kernel installed (but not running), the Nvidia 535 module will compile (on the previous 5.19 or 6.2 kernel) using the gcc-12. The is a cutoff though on older cards -- that may be your problem.

Comment: Try just installing the gcc-12 and see if you can select/rebuild the Nvidia module.  For awhile, the automatic gcc-12 download with the 6.5 kernel didn't occur.

Comment: This issue is fixed with 6.5.0-25

Answer (score 0):

**This issue seems to be fixed with 6.5.0-25**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1343175)